# Possible to use "greater than" / "less than" in Scope Rules?

Tags: search, search-scope

At first glance it appears that they force you to use "equals" as the operator.  Does anyone know of a way to setup a rule that allows you to use "less than" and "greater than"?

If not, would it be possible to customize the `matchingrule.aspx` page and it's supporting code to do this without venturing into "unsupported" territory?

Answer (score 1):

I think its possible to achieve this...(Sharepoint 2010)

Add a core results webpart in your matchingrule.aspx page, go to the edit webpart properties window expand the "Result Query Options" tab and add ManagedPropertyName "<" Value or ManagedPropertyName ">" Value" (no quotes) inside the "Append Text to Query" textbox and do a search to test it out and it should work..

keep in mind this only applies to DateTime, Integer and Decimal Managed property types.

For for information on property restrictions for searching..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394509.aspx